# An exercise in Number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m$, $n$ and $k$ be positive integers with gcd$(mn, k) = 1$. How can I prove that $x^m + y^n = z^k $has a solution in positive integers?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps if you share any thoughts you have or what you have tried. Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for solutions of the shape $x=2^a$, $y=2^b$, $z=2^c$. A little thinking shows that we want $am=bn$, with each equal to $ck-1$. And now Bézout's Theorem comes into play.